# Vertically scroll multiple background images within div along with text

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, background-image

How would I go about creating this kind of vertical scroll in the least obtuse way? I think I'm planning this all wrong.

[image]

I currently have a `div` with a `background-image`, and the (1) / (2) / etc with negative positioning and higher `z-index` than that `div`, affixed on top.

My thinking was to create a JS listener to each paragraph, and change the background image when triggered. But that won't help me make it scroll up like that so I'm thinking I'm going about it the wrong way.

Ideally I want the images to scroll in the same way the paragraph does, so that it looks 'natural'. But nesting multiple divs on top of each other with masks and turning display on:off seems a bit too crazy.

Answer (score 0):

So a way I think this could be done:

You essentially want to create that window that you see the background images in...

So create a fixed element with a z-index something like 10 and then your images at a z-index of 1 so they are behind the window. Then set the z-index of your text to 20 so its on top of everything.

Here is a very basic snippet:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LzQrYa

Code:

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="cover top"></div>
  <div class="cover right"></div>
  <div class="cover bottom"></div>
  <div class="cover left"></div>
  <div class="bg-image one"></div>
  <div class="bg-image two"></div>
  <div class="bg-image three"></div>

  <p class="text one">Text 1</p>
  <p class="text two">Text 1</p>
  <p class="text three">Text 1</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
.container .cover {
  position: fixed;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  z-index: 10;
}
.container .cover.top { 
  top: 0; left: 0; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 120px;
}
.container .cover.right { 
  top: 0; right: 0; 
  width: 100px; 
  height: 100%;
}
.container .cover.bottom { 
  bottom: 0; left: 0; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 120px;
}
.container .cover.left { 
  top: 0; left: 0; 
  width: 500px; 
  height: 100%;
}
.container .bg-image {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  float: left;
}
.container .bg-image.one { background-color: #cccccc; }
.container .bg-image.two { background-color: #8ec640; }
.container .bg-image.three { background-color: #ff00ff; }

.container .text {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #000000;
  z-index: 20;
}
.container .text.one {
  top: 40px;
  left: 50px;
}
.container .text.two {
  top: 500px;
  left: 50px;
}
.container .text.three {
  top: 940px;
  left: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Hey there, thank you for writing this out! This is definitely interesting and does look great. I was hoping for a way to keep the images as background-image for the div, since I have the numeric badges (1) / (2) etc affixed on top with negative spacing.

Comment: Hi :) No worries. Im sorry I couldnt help! If you are wanring to use background images that should be easy to swap out on my example? I think I might be misunderstanding with the badges thing because I'm not quite sure what you mean :)

Comment: Oh in the GIF there are two black circles with "1" + "2" :) I have them as negative positioning

Comment: @Malah I'm not quite sure how to get them to do what you are wanting to do though. maybe if you make a different gif showing how it swaps from 1 to 2...I think I might still be misunderstanding though haha